# Return value only of the faster coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How can I run multiple coroutines in parallel and return only the value of the one that finishes first?

Real-life scenario, I have two data sources - *Database* and *API service*. I don't care where does the data originate from, I just need it fast. How can I query both *Database* and *API service* and cancel the other request when the one finishes?

In RxJava world this would be equal to [Amb operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/amb.html). How can I achieve similar behaviour using coroutines?

Answer (score 10):

I came up with following  implementation:

```
suspend fun getFaster(): Int = coroutineScope {
    select<Int> {
        async { getFromServer() }.onAwait { it }
        async { getFromDB() }.onAwait { it }
    }.also {
        coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```

The `coroutineScope` acts as a parent to all async calls performed within. After the `select` finishes we can just cancel the rest.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `select` to write your own `amb` operator. Something like that:

```
suspend fun <T> amb(vararg jobs: Deferred<T>): T = select {
    fun cancelAll() = jobs.forEach { it.cancel() }

    for (deferred in jobs) {
        deferred.onAwait {
            cancelAll()
            it
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about `select` expression [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/select-expression.html)

Comment: This works but you have to cancel the job manually :( imagine if there are more than two coroutine in that select block :(. You would then have to do `d1.onAwait { d2.cancel() d3.cancel() d4.cancel() it }`. Cancelling the job manually makes this function not scale well :(

Comment: There should be something like a `selectAndCancel { }` to handle situations like this.

Comment: you're right. At first, I wrote just a simple version. Now I've changed it to the generic one.

Comment: Thats better! +1 :D